# Lazy Loading gridview from json

Tags: c#, json, gridview, uwp, lazy-loading

I have a lazy loading in gridview whose data is taken from JSON.

Sample of JSON:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "total_data": 32,
    "data_per_page": "16",
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_page": 2,
    "current_total": 16,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "2613",
            "judul": "Kamus ID EN",
            "slug": "kamus-id-en",
            "cover": "https://mhnkp2.com/src/umum/cover/kamus_ID_EN-thumb.jpg",
            "path": "https://mhnkp2.com/school/dl/dodl/2613",
            "ukuran": "3504835",
            "formated_size": "3.34 MB",
            "fname": "kamus_ID_EN.pdf",
            "publish": "1",
            "urgent": "400",
            "kelas": "0",
            "nama_kelas": "Umum"
        },
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="content" Grid.Row="1" Loaded="MainGrid_Loaded">

            <GridView
                x:Name="itemGridView"
                Loaded="itemGridView_Loaded">

                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid
                            Width="135"
                            Height="280"
                            Margin="5,5,5,5"
                            Background="White">
                                <TextBlock
                                    x:Name="title"
                                    Margin="0,0,10,10"
                                    FontSize="14"
                                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding Judul}"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Buku> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Buku>();
int offset = 0;
        private void MainGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
                        Umum(1);
                    } 
    public class Buku
        {
            public string Judul { get; set; }
        }

            private async void Umum(int offset)
            {
                urlPath = "https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/umum";
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("halaman", offset.ToString()),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("limit", "16"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt")
                };

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                try
                {
                    double total = groupObject1["total_data"].GetNumber();
                    double pages = groupObject1["total_page"].GetNumber();
                    double page = groupObject1["current_page"].GetNumber();

                    Buku file = new Buku();
                    file.PageNo = Convert.ToInt32(page);
                    file.Pages = Convert.ToInt32(pages);
                    file.Total = Convert.ToInt32(total);
                    JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();
                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();
                        string title = groupObject2["judul"].GetString();

                        Buku file1 = new Buku();
                        file1.Judul = title;
                        datasource.Add(file1);
                    }
                    itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
                }
            }

            private void itemGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        ScrollViewer viewer = GetScrollViewer(this.itemGridView);
                        viewer.ViewChanged += Viewer_ViewChanged;
                    }

                    private void Viewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        ScrollViewer view = (ScrollViewer)sender;
                        double progress = view.VerticalOffset / view.ScrollableHeight;
                        //Debug.WriteLine(progress);
                        if (progress > 0.7 && !incall && !endoflist)
                        {
                            incall = true;
                            busyindicator.IsActive = true;
                            Umum(++offset);
                        }
                    }

                    public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
                    {
                        if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

                        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                        {
                            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
                            if (result != null) return result;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
```

I am having a problem, that the gridview should display data on pages 1 and 2, but in the gridview the data displayed on page 2 is a repetition of data on page 1, as shown below:
[image: picture]
How to fix it?

Note:

- The page uses the "offset" parameter
- The page limit is "total_page" in JSON

Comment: are you sure you are getting the different data from 2 request in json ? if its different then check you are concatenate the 2 json data to the same list. before assign the list first clear the datagrid datasoure by passing NULL and then add 1 and 2 concatenate list as datasource

Comment: @ketan The data I got on the gridview is the same data on page 1 and is repeated 2 times (failed to retrieve data on page 2)

Comment: try to pass NULL to `itemGridView.ItemsSource = NULL;` and then add `itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;` and then check in `Umum`

Comment: where did you decare the `datasource` and `offset`  ? please post the clear code

Comment: @ketan The problem is when I debug, the pages in parameter offset are 1 both

Comment: @ketan i have edited the code above

Comment: If you set the offset as 1 at first like `int offset = 1;`, will the same issue occur? Since in MainGrid_Loaded method, you have loaded the data from first page, when you scroll the gridView, you need to load the second page instead of first page.

Comment: first set offset  0 to 1  and then pass the offset value in `MainGrid_Loaded` like `Umum(offset )`

Comment: in `MainGrid_Loaded` you are passing `Umum(1)` manually one and when `Viewer_ViewChanged` passing the `Umum(++offset)` but your offset is will increment zero to one.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass the offset value to `MainGrid_Loaded` and set offset zero to one

```
ObservableCollection<Buku> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Buku>();
int offset = 1; // set offset zero to one 
        private void MainGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
                        Umum(offset); // just change 1 to offset 
                    } 
    public class Buku
        {
            public string Judul { get; set; }
        }

            private async void Umum(int offset)
            {
                urlPath = "mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1";
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("halaman", offset.ToString()),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("limit", "16"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt")
                };

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                try
                {
                    double total = groupObject1["total_data"].GetNumber();
                    double pages = groupObject1["total_page"].GetNumber();
                    double page = groupObject1["current_page"].GetNumber();

                    Buku file = new Buku();
                    file.PageNo = Convert.ToInt32(page);
                    file.Pages = Convert.ToInt32(pages);
                    file.Total = Convert.ToInt32(total);
                    JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();
                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();
                        string title = groupObject2["judul"].GetString();

                        Buku file1 = new Buku();
                        file1.Judul = title;
                        datasource.Add(file1);
                    }
                    itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
                }
            }

            private void itemGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        ScrollViewer viewer = GetScrollViewer(this.itemGridView);
                        viewer.ViewChanged += Viewer_ViewChanged;
                    }

                    private void Viewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        ScrollViewer view = (ScrollViewer)sender;
                        double progress = view.VerticalOffset / view.ScrollableHeight;
                        //Debug.WriteLine(progress);
                        if (progress > 0.7 && !incall && !endoflist)
                        {
                            incall = true;
                            busyindicator.IsActive = true;
                            Umum(offset++);
                        }
                    }

                    public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
                    {
                        if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

                        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                        {
                            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
                            if (result != null) return result;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
```

Comment: This code is used successfully if the number of pages is only 2. If more than 2, then the data displayed on the gridview is only page 2 only. Because for links: https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1 the number of pages is 5. How to handle it?

Comment: are you sure your back end logic works prefect after passing page number 3 or 4 or 5 it gives different data every time ?

Comment: i am sure my above code works for all n number pages. would you please post your full code of the grid page class. n also your json data because your above json sample shows number of pages count is 2. Again  please recheck the page count manually. please verify manually database record pages count

Comment: The code above is full code. Only change urlPath = "https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/umum"; to urlPath = "https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1";

Comment: the url is "https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1"

Comment: here the respon at postman: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7UgYJ05xcwoUvOQFp4Lw?e=zj0hE2

Comment: for urlpath definitely use the link:  https://mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1 (not using offset). Because offset is the "halaman" parameter (not the link)

Comment: i want to ask a last question where do you send the page number in this link ??? (mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1 ) the 1 is your page number or what >???

Comment: That is the link address, so it does not require offsite. Offsite is used for parameter "halaman"

Comment: new KeyValuePair<string, string>("halaman", offset.ToString())

Comment: post the link for page number 2

Comment: mhnkp2.com/school/api-v3/fetch/ktsp2006/kelas/1. The page using parameter new KeyValuePair<string, string>("halaman", offset.ToString())

Comment: Here the screenshot: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7UgYJ1SrpHr171qSB7mg?e=L7maXI

Comment: With this code, the data displayed on the gridview is only page 1 and when scrolled gridview will add data on page 1 again. Cannot display data on pages 2, 3, etc.

Comment: are you sure you copied my code correctly ??  `int offset = 1;` have you declared the offset to 1 ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207645/discussion-between-ketan-and-rose).